# android studio: auto scroll down and link textViews to scroll together

Tags: java, android, scroll, textview, scrollview

I have two `TextViews` that are childs of a `ScrollView`. Both `TextViews` are supposed to have the same identical lines and texts (so same hight of text).

I have two questions:

1. (Question 1) how can I auto scroll the ScrollView to the last line of any of my TextViews (they both have the same height) so that when a new line is inserted in my TextViews it should be visible as the last line in my ScrollView.
   Note: I do not want to set the gravity to the bottom because I want the first inserted lines to start from the top and grow downward (similar to inserting line in a Chat, when new line is inserted the bottom is visible)
2. (Question 2) is there a way to auto scroll both TextViews at the same time when the ScrollView is scrolled up or down?

The following is my `ScrollView` element in my `activity_main.xml`

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Sheets"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/theirScoreTotalLarge">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Sheet1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#1FFF"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                ads:layout_goneMarginLeft="16dp"
                ads:layout_goneMarginRight="16dp"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="1dp"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="352dp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/VerticalLine2"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="0">

            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Sheet2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#1FFF"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                ads:layout_goneMarginLeft="16dp"
                ads:layout_goneMarginRight="16dp"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="1dp"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="352dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```